# GemaltoXpress Applet Upload Issue

Tags: smartcard, javacard, gemalto

I'm in the process of developing an applet to reside and run on Java Cards, and I've been evaluating different cards. I have a bunch of GemaltoXpress cards with 32kb of EEPROM, but despite doing my best, I haven't been able to upload even an empty applet to them. I'm using [Global Platform for SmartCardIO Java SDK library](http://gpj.sourceforge.net) to communicate with cards. My applet looks like this:

```
package test.package;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;

public class TestApplet extends Applet {

    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
        new TestApplet();
    }

    /**
     * Only this class's install method should create the applet object.
     */
    protected TestApplet() {
        register();
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
    }
}
```

But this fails to upload onto GemaltoXpress cards with SW12=0x6985 right after the first `80 E8 00 00 FF ...` APDU. I'm compiling my applet against JAVA Card Kit 2.2.1 with `-source 1.2 -target 1.1` parameters passed to `javac`. My `.opt` file looks like this:

```
-nobanner
-out EXP JCA CAP
-exportpath C:\java_card_kit-2_2_1\api_export_files
-d ..\dist
-applet  0x00:0x00:0x50:0x50:0x50:0x50:0x50:0x50:0x50:0x50:0x50:0x00 test.package.TestApplet test.package
0x00:0x00:0x50:0x50:0x50:0x50:0x50:0x50:0x50:0x50:0x50 1.0
```

I'm puzzled as to why GemaltoXpress cards don't like this applet, while NXP's SmartMX cards are fine with it. Am I missing something? Is there a special requirement when you develop for GemaltoXpress?

Comment: Are you using correct keys to establish secure channel?

Comment: @MohammadBanisaeid Yes. I can issue administrative commands such as `list` without any problem.

Comment: Could it be that the API has changed between versions and you are linking against the wrong version? Note that versions issues are less a problem with Java SE, where everything is dynamically linked.

Comment: @owlstead It might as well be, but I'm compiling against the oldest version of Java Card SDK available to me, 2.2.1.